# Storing the name of a function in a structure to call later

Tags: c

I want to store the name of several functions so that later after doing test on them I can call them if needed, how can I accomplish this>. Here's an example:

```
typedef struct parser_rule {
    tk_type type;
    ???? function_ptr; // type???
} parser_rule;

void expr(void) { return; }
void ident(void) { return; }

int main(void) {
    parser_rule* this = {lala, expr};
    this->function_ptr();
    this->function_ptr = {meemee, ident};
    this->function_ptr();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `type_of_result(*function_ptr)(type_of_params);`

Comment: Search for and read about *function pointers*.